# How do you create your own filename extension that works on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, filenames, file-extension

I created a .pdf file that I called dhwd7486.pdf, because I want to create something great (this is included), I renamed the file extension into .unused (cuz I use it occasionally), but I thought it will work the same as a .pdf (note: i'm not a developer nor a programmer), so I opened it and I can't. Thank god I named it by it's contents so what I only do is to copy the title. but I want the experience of having my own filename extension working (I don't want to change it into .pdf again). can you help me how to do that (having my own file extension working)?

Comment: Just chiming in because it sounds like you feel the file is lost. I get this feeling because you said "Thank god I named it by it's contents." Changing the file extension does not alter the actual 1's and 0's of the file at all - you can simply change the extension back to .pdf and the file will be exactly as it was before you changed it.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is rename it *dhwd7486.unknown*.

Now, to get that new extension to open in your PDF viewer (e.g. Firefox, Sumatra or other application),

- *Right-click* on the file.
- Select **Open with**.
- Select **Try an app on this PC**.
- Browse to the application you want to use to open that type of file.
- Check the box for **Always use this app to open .unknown files**.
- Click **OK**.

Comment: There is no need to rename it to .unknown, they can keep the .unused file extension and still use the procedure you explain to achieve the desired effect.